# How to get Database details from settings.py

Tags: django, python-2.7, settings

I am a newbie in python. I need to access a python file from another file in another directory. In particular I want to be able to see these database details which are in a file named settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dynamic',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '192.168.10.130',
    }
}
```

How do I access this dictionary as a database from another file in another folder?

I have tried to do it like this (which works in my other project):

```
from django.conf import settings
dbHost = settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST']
dbUsername = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER']
dbPassword = settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']
dbName = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: didn't get your problem. Can you say more about 2 projects (with examples)?

Comment: @Satevg What all the details u need more. I am using this tutorial  for creation of my projects. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/.And i done the basic thing from this tutorial then i try to get the database values

Comment: Why do you think you need this? The database settings are for Django's internal use, you shouldn't need to access them in the view.

Comment: yes I know that and I access it in the view page, but i need to add an additional file into my project and In that file I need to access the database details

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `projectA.settings.DATABASES` in **projectB** then you should add **projectA** path in **projectB**:

**projectB**/myfile.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append( "/path/to/projectA" )
from projectA import settings

dbHost     = settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST']
dbUsername = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER']
dbPassword = settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']
dbName     = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']
```

Comment: thanks for your answer its right because first i do this method.but I need import settings from dango.conf without using sys.path

Comment: because when i give to the production always need to change the path.To avoiding that I need to use djano.conf or like a smililar method dynamically access that values

Comment: You can append a relative path to the current working directory, this way it will work in development and production. Otherwise use a project-root variable in your deployment scripts.

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.DATABASES
{'default': 
    {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
    'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 3600,
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'NAME': 'proj',
    'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8', 'sql_mode': 'traditional'},
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'PORT': '20306',
    'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'MIRROR': None, 'NAME': None},
    'TIME_ZONE': None,
    'USER': 'root'}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard coding your credentials in python, you can use [dj-database-url](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url) to easily load DB settings from an environment variable.

Another option would be using `json.load()` and a small json file.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the settings.py of project 2, you can import project1 settings file as:

```
import project1.settings
```

and then initialize the DATABASES as:

```
DATABASES = { 'default': project1.settings.DATABASES['default'] }
```